# Radio input not changing value?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a radio input that is not changing values when selected. It is simply saying `Domain` is the value all the time.

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
         <label class="radio-inline" for="AccountType_Domain"> <input id="AccountType_Domain" name="AccountType" type="radio" value="Domain">Domain</label>
        <label class="radio-inline" for="AccountType_Local"> <input id="AccountType_Local" name="AccountType" type="radio" value="Local">Local</label>
 </div>
```

At first I was using `@html.RadioButtonFor` but that was causing the 2  inputs to have the same id.

When executing `$("input:radio[AccountType]").val()` I am only getting `Domain` no matter what is selected.

Comment: You are missing the `:checked` selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the :checked css selector.

So, to get the value of the selected AccountType item in jQuery, it will look as follows:

`$('input[name=AccountType]:checked').val()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```js
$("input[name='AccountType']:checked").val()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-2">
         <label class="radio-inline" for="AccountType_Domain"> <input id="AccountType_Domain" name="AccountType" type="radio" value="Domain" checked>Domain</label>
        <label class="radio-inline" for="AccountType_Local"> <input id="AccountType_Local" name="AccountType" type="radio" value="Local">Local</label>
 </div>
```